# Does Dapper has a support sql_variant DataType

Tags: c#, ado.net, dapper, sqlclient

Sql Server Schema that I am working with has `sql_variant` DataType as a part of `Table Type Parameter` Column. Also there's non TVP parameter which is `sql_variant`. For the TVP parameter, I have used the option provided in the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52736573/1559611

It have used `List<SqlDataRecord>`, which can be added to the `DynamicParameters`, since `AsTableValuedParameter()` has an extension method for `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`.

Before trying the above option I have tried mapping an `object` and `string` type to `sql_variant` for a TVP column, but that leads to the exception.

Now I am trying to figure out:

- How to map a non TVP parameter for Dapper, since I don't see an option similar to `SqlDataRecord`, would a simple `object` type work in that case ?
- When return collection contains column, which is of variant type, will it map to an `object` type ?

My only option, if Dapper doesn't support is to switch back to SqlClient, which does have an explicit support for Sql_Variant data type, which doesn't seems to be case for Dapper as it use `DbType`, which has no explicit Variant data type

Any help or pointer on these cases ?

Comment: `DbType.Object` seems like it ought to be the equivalent of `SqlDbType.Variant` but I've not tried to use it myself (since the quirks and limitations of the type means I avoid it. TBH, I thought it had been deprecated but it would appear not)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No that doesn't help, leads to exception, nothing which maps to `SqlDbType.Variant`, cursing the database developer using the pointless variant type

Comment: According to [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings), `Sql_variant` maps to `SqlDbType.Variant` and `DbType.Object` - However I must Agree with Damien on this - `sql_variant` is something I avoid using. In fact, in over a decade of working with sql server, I don't remember using that data type even once.

Comment: Can dapper map to the supported sql_variant data type?

Comment: It does except a specific case where Sql Variant is part of TVP, there it doesn't and needs ADO.NET